# JAXB unable to marshal type "java.lang.Class"

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I want to write a XML file, I have the entity class which contains mapped objects.
I added annotations.Now i have a button in JSF page which generate the XML file, but in the output file i found just the main class without the other mapped class which I've a the annotations.
this is my mainClass:

package esprit.olap.domain;

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Schema")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "parameters", "cubes", "dimensions", "catalogBase" })
@Entity
public class SchemaBase implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id_schema;  

private String name_schema;

private String description_schema;

private String measuresCaption_schema;

private String defaultRole_schema;


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private CatalogBase catalogBase;




@OneToMany (cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.ALL})
private List<CubeBase>cubes ;

@OneToMany (cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.ALL})
private List<ParameterBase>parameters;

@ManyToMany
private List<DimensionBase> dimensions;



public List<ParameterBase> getParameters() {
    return parameters;
}
@XmlElement(name="Parameter")
public void setParameters(List<ParameterBase> parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
}
public List<DimensionBase> getDimensions() {
    return dimensions;
}
@XmlElement(name="Dimension")
public void setDimensions(List<DimensionBase> dimensions) {
    this.dimensions = dimensions;
}

public List<CubeBase> getCubes() {
    return cubes;
}
@XmlElement(name="Cube")
public void setCubes(List<CubeBase> cubes) {
    this.cubes = cubes;
}
public CatalogBase getCatalogBase() {
    return catalogBase;
}
public void setCatalogBase(CatalogBase catalogBase) {
    this.catalogBase = catalogBase;
}
public int getId_schema() {
    return id_schema;
}
@XmlTransient
public void setId_schema(int id_schema) {
    this.id_schema = id_schema;
}
public String getName_schema() {
    return name_schema;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="name")
public void setName_schema(String name_schema) {
    this.name_schema = name_schema;
}
public String getDescription_schema() {
    return description_schema;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="description")
public void setDescription_schema(String description_schema) {
    this.description_schema = description_schema;
}
public String getMeasuresCaption_schema() {
    return measuresCaption_schema;
}
@XmlTransient
public void setMeasuresCaption_schema(String measuresCaption_schema) {
    this.measuresCaption_schema = measuresCaption_schema;
}
public String getDefaultRole_schema() {
    return defaultRole_schema;
}
@XmlAttribute(name="defaultValue")
public void setDefaultRole_schema(String defaultRole_schema) {
    this.defaultRole_schema = defaultRole_schema;
}


public void addCubeToShema(List<CubeBase> cubes){
       for(CubeBase cubeBase:cubes)
           cubeBase.setSchema(this);
       this.cubes=cubes;
   }
public void addParameterToSchema(List<ParameterBase> parameters){
    for(ParameterBase param:parameters)
        param.setSchema(this);
    this.parameters=parameters;
}
public SchemaBase(String name_schema, String description_schema,
        String measuresCaption_schema, String defaultRole_schema,
        List<CubeBase> cubes, List<ParameterBase> parameters,
        List<DimensionBase> dimensions) {
    super();
    this.name_schema = name_schema;
    this.description_schema = description_schema;
    this.measuresCaption_schema = measuresCaption_schema;
    this.defaultRole_schema = defaultRole_schema;
    this.cubes = cubes;
    this.parameters = parameters;
    this.dimensions = dimensions;
}

public SchemaBase(String name_schema,List<CubeBase> cubes, List<ParameterBase> parameters,
        List<DimensionBase> dimensions) {
    super();
    this.name_schema = name_schema;
    this.cubes = cubes;
    this.parameters = parameters;
    this.dimensions = dimensions;
}
public SchemaBase(String name_schema) {
    super();
    this.name_schema = name_schema;
}
public SchemaBase() {
    super();
}


}
```

This is my ManagedBean for SchemaBase :

```
@ManagedBean(name="SchemaMan")
@SessionScoped
public class SchemaManaged {

    @EJB
     SchemaDaoRemote schemaService;

    //private SchemaBase schema;
    public SchemaBase schema = new SchemaBase();
    private WriteXml xl= new WriteXml();

    private String roleSchema;
    private String descSchema;
    private String nameSchema;
    private TreeNode shemaBoxses;
    private TreeNode shemaBoxse;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

     shemaBoxses = new DefaultTreeNode("Schema", null);
     TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Schema",  shemaBoxses);



 }

    public String getRoleSchema() {
        return roleSchema;
    }
    public void setRoleSchema(String roleSchema) {
        this.roleSchema = roleSchema;
    }
    public String getDescSchema() {
        return descSchema;
    }
    public void setDescSchema(String descSchema) {
        this.descSchema = descSchema;
    }


    public SchemaBase getSchema() {
        return schema;
    }

    public void setSchema(SchemaBase schema) {
        this.schema = schema;
    }

    public String getNameSchema() {
        return nameSchema;
    }
    public void setNameSchema(String nameSchema) {
        this.nameSchema = nameSchema;
    }
    public TreeNode getShemaBoxse() {
        return shemaBoxse;
    }
    public void setShemaBoxse(TreeNode shemaBoxse) {
        this.shemaBoxse = shemaBoxse;
    }
    public TreeNode getShemaBoxses() {
        return shemaBoxses;
    }
    public void setShemaBoxses(TreeNode shemaBoxses) {
        this.shemaBoxses = shemaBoxses;
    }

    public String CreateSchema(){
        System.out.println(schema.getName_schema());
        schema = schemaService.create_schema(schema);

        FacesContext context= FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Schema "+schema.getName_schema()+" ajouter avec succees", ""));
        return "Scucces";


}


}
```

and for the Service of SchemaBase:

```
public interface SchemaDaoRemote {

    public SchemaBase create_schema (SchemaBase schema);
    public void update_schema (SchemaBase schema);
    public void delete_schema(int id);
    public List<SchemaBase>list_schema(int id);
    public SchemaBase find_schema(int id);


}
```

i create onther Managed bean like this :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "xmlMan")
@SessionScoped
public class XmlGenaratedManaged {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{SchemaMan}")
    SchemaManaged shmanged;
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{paraMan}")
    ParameterManaged param;



public SchemaManaged getShmanged() {
        return shmanged;
    }



    public void setShmanged(SchemaManaged shmanged) {
        this.shmanged = shmanged;
    }




    public ParameterManaged getParam() {
        return param;
    }



    public void setParam(ParameterManaged param) {
        this.param = param;
    }



public void GenerateXml(){
    //SchemaBase schema = new SchemaBase();
    shmanged.schema.setParameters(new ArrayList<ParameterBase>());
    //ParameterBase pb=param.getParamUpdate();
    //schema.getParameters().add(pb);

    shmanged.schema.getParameters().add(param.getParamUpdate());

        JAXBContext jaxbContext;

        try {

            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(SchemaBase.class);

            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            System.out.println("This is your cube"+shmanged.getSchema().getParameters());
            //specify the location and name of xml file to be created
            File XMLfile = new File("C:\\EspritJSF.xml");
            // for getting nice formatted output  
               jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);


            // Writing to XML file
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(shmanged.getSchema(), XMLfile); 


            // Writing to console
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(shmanged.getSchema(), System.out); 
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

}
```

but when i added for exemple 2 ParamterBase and when i run it i got only the last parameter in my XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Schema defaultValue="" description="fdsd" name="fdg">
    <Parameter defaultValue="dffdfd" description="fdsf" modifiable="false" name="dfd" type="Timestamp"/>
</Schema>
```

so how can i have my two parameter in my XML file and thx all for your help.

Comment: you need to have Schema.class instead of schema.class

Comment: where is your schema object istantiated that you are using in jaxbMarshaller.marshal(schema, System.out); ?

Comment: Try to use JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("package.of.your.schema.class");

Comment: Are the mapped classes populated? If they are null or empty, I don't think you'll get any content for your class object when you attempt to marshal. The type is working fine because you're getting the proper tag when you marshal, it's just the data that's missing. Can we see the code where your `schema` object is populated?

Comment: yes i have instead my SchemaBase like this : public SchemaBase schema = new SchemaBase(); into my Schema Managed Bean

Comment: The title is grossly misleading: you aren't marshalling type "java.lang.Class" - the type is "SchemaBase". Also, the XML output doesn't match what you've shown of this class, which is confusing. Please show all fields of SchemaBase and, above all, add the full code for creating and populating `SchemaBase schema.

Comment: Class SchemaBase is OK (although I would add `= new ArrayList<>()` to the three List field declarations). If fields are set, the corresponding elements will appear in the marshalled XML.

Answer (score 1):

You have your classes and everything set up right, but based on what you see, your schema object is not being populated properly.
I constructed a set of classes to mimic what you've described here with some arbitrary content and was able to marshal fine.

The types:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Parameter")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ParameterBase {
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    public String paramName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Value")
    public String paramValue;

    public ParameterBase() {}

    public void setParamName(String paramName) { this.paramName = paramName; }
    public void setParamValue(String paramValue) { this.paramValue = paramValue; }
    public String getParamName() { return this.paramName; }
    public String getParamValue() { return this.paramValue; }
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "Cube")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CubeBase {
    @XmlElement(name = "X")
    int x;
    @XmlElement(name = "Y")
    int y;
    @XmlElement(name = "Z")
    int z;

    public CubeBase() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public int getZ() {
        return this.z;
    }

    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
    public void setZ(int z) { this.z = z; }
} 



@XmlRootElement(name = "Dimension")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DimensionBase {
    @XmlElement(name = "Value")
    int dim;

    public DimensionBase() {
        dim = 0;
    }

    public void setDim(int dim) { this.dim = dim; }
    public int getDim() { return this.dim; }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Catalog")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CatalogBase {
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    String catalogName;

    public CatalogBase() {

    }

    public void setCatalogName(String name) {
        this.catalogName = name;
    }

    public String getCatalogName() {
        return this.catalogName;
    }
}
```

The schema type:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Schema")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "parameters", "cubes", "dimensions", "catalogBase" })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SchemaBase {
    @XmlElement(name = "Parameter")
    List<ParameterBase> parameters;
    @XmlElement(name = "Cube")
    List<CubeBase> cubes;
    @XmlElement(name = "Dimension")
    List<DimensionBase> dimensions;
    @XmlElement(name = "CatalogBase")
    CatalogBase catalogBase;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "defaultValue")
    String defaultValue;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "description")
    String description;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    String name;

    public SchemaBase() {
        defaultValue = "dsf";
        description = "sdfsd";
        name = "dsq";
    }

    public SchemaBase(String defaultValue, String description, String name) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        this.description = description;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<ParameterBase> getParameters() { return this.parameters; }
    public List<CubeBase> getCubes() { return this.cubes; }
    public List<DimensionBase> getDimensions() { return this.dimensions; }
    public CatalogBase getCatalogBase() { return this.catalogBase; }

    public void setParameters(List<ParameterBase> parameters ) { this.parameters = parameters;}
    public void setCubes(List<CubeBase> cubes ) { this.cubes = cubes;}
    public void setDimensions(List<DimensionBase> dimensions ) { this.dimensions = dimensions;}
    public void setCatalogBase(CatalogBase catalogBase) { this.catalogBase = catalogBase; }
}
```

With the following simple test:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaBase schema = new SchemaBase("Default", "MySchema", "MySchemaName");

        CatalogBase cb = new CatalogBase();
        cb.setCatalogName("My Catalog");
        schema.setCatalogBase(cb);

        schema.setDimensions(new ArrayList<DimensionBase>());
        DimensionBase db = new DimensionBase();
        db.setDim(12);
        schema.getDimensions().add(db);
        db = new DimensionBase();
        db.setDim(14);
        schema.getDimensions().add(db);
        db = new DimensionBase();
        db.setDim(50);
        schema.getDimensions().add(db);

        schema.setCubes(new ArrayList<CubeBase>());
        CubeBase cube = new CubeBase();
        cube.setX(3);
        cube.setY(13);
        cube.setZ(20);
        schema.getCubes().add(cube);

        schema.setParameters(new ArrayList<ParameterBase>());
        ParameterBase pb = new ParameterBase();
        pb.setParamName("MyParamName");
        pb.setParamValue("MyParamValue");
        schema.getParameters().add(pb);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{schema.getClass()});
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal(schema, System.out);
    }
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Schema defaultValue="Default" description="MySchema" name="MySchemaName">
    <Parameter>
        <Name>MyParamName</Name>
        <Value>MyParamValue</Value>
    </Parameter>
    <Cube>
        <X>3</X>
        <Y>13</Y>
        <Z>20</Z>
    </Cube>
    <Dimension>
        <Value>12</Value>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension>
        <Value>14</Value>
    </Dimension>
    <Dimension>
        <Value>50</Value>
    </Dimension>
    <CatalogBase>
        <Name>My Catalog</Name>
    </CatalogBase>
</Schema>
```

If `schema` is created and nothing else is populated, the following is observed:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SchemaBase schema = new SchemaBase("Default", "MySchema", "MySchemaName");

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{schema.getClass()});
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        m.marshal(schema, System.out);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Schema defaultValue="Default" description="MySchema" name="MySchemaName"/>
```

Examine your schema object and make sure it's fully populated.

Comment: i make a test like you did instance for each time CubeBase and the other object and when i passed the SchemaBase.Class it work fine but in my JSF page when i added the cubeBase to the main Object SchemaBase in my data base i can see that the CubeBase it associate with the same SchemaBase but when i run my code he only show me the xml for The SchemaBase.

Comment: You're going to have to paste the code you are using to set up your objects. I'm having trouble following.

Comment: you can see the all code now ans thanks for your help

Comment: and when i wrote this code : System.out.println("Parameter return"+schema.getParameters()); i get null but when i go to database i see that this parameters is associated to this schema !!!!